# Is ethylene diamine tetra acetate a misnomer?

Tags: nomenclature

Since there is no double bond, I thought EDTA should be ethane... instead. Am I missing something? 
I understand this is not the complete IUPAC name, but why name it wrong on purpose?

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't EDTA have a double bond?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7548/7951) and [Why are PTFE and FEP named “ethylene” when they don't have double bonds?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/23786/7951)