# Why the common name of 1,2-dichloro-ethane is ethylene dichloride if it has no double bonds in it?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Why the common name of 1,2-dichloro-ethane is ethyl*ene* dichloride if it has no double bonds in it? The -ene in the common name suggests that it should have a double bond. I believe this is due to the fact that ethylene dichloride is a derivative of ethylene and synthesised from it but I was told that the presence of -ene is due to the two chlorine atoms? I don't think this is correct. What's the actual answer?

Comment: Related: [1](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7548/103369), [2](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/48776/103369), [3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/23786/103369)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia Article on 1,2-Dichloroethane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,2-Dichloroethane), it is known by many names:

- Ethylene dichloride
- Ethylene chloride
- 1,2-DCE
- DCE
- Ethane dichloride
- Dutch liquid
- Dutch oil
- Freon 150

The, misleading, name of ethylene dichloride originates from its method of production; [ethylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene) is a common name for ethene, which upon reaction with [dichlorine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine) (a more accurate name for $\ce{Cl2}$, commonly known as chlorine) produces ethylene dichloride.

[image: reaction between ethylene and dichlorine to form ethylene dichloride]

There aren't many sources to track down exactly when ethylene dichloride became popular. Another possible explanation is that it is derived from the name [methylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methylene_(compound)) (IUPAC name: methylidene, also called carbene or methene). Consider the following hypothetical reaction.

[image: reaction between two methylene and dichlorine to form ethylene dichloride]

Unfortunately, accurate nomenclature was not the first priority of 18$^\text{th}$ and 19$^\text{th}$ century chemists and industrialists; moreover, according to [Wikipedia article on IUPAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_nomenclature_of_chemistry), it was only established in the early 20$^\text{th}$ century, and it took time to standardize nomenclature.

[Google Trends](https://trends.google.co.in/trends/explore?hl=en-GB) shows that the name, ethylene dichloride is, more or less, consistently employed, especially in India, United Arab Emirates, and some parts of the USA:

[image: google trends for interest of ethylene dichloride]

However, Dutch oil is more common worldwide:

[image: google trends comparing ethylene dichloride to dutch oil]

Answer (score 3):

Ethylene is

- the name for the bidental functional group $\ce{\bond{-}CH2-CH2\bond{-}}$

  - Similarly,  $\ce{\bond{-}CH2\bond{-}}$ is methylene and $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ can be called also as methylene dichloride, aside of IUPAC preferred name dichloromethane.
  - Therefore, $\ce{Cl-CH2-CH2-Cl}$ can be called also as ethylene dichloride
- the older name for ethene $\ce{CH2=CH2}$.

Distinguishing is as usually context dependent.